# How can I use a specific font only when the user is running Linux?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to detect a Operating system using JQuery or CSS? With CSS I'm referring to something similar to `<![if !IE]>`

I need to use a specific font only when web page is viewed using Linux and don't want to include this with other os's

Comment: For fonts in particular, you can specify a list and if the first font is not found on that particular system, the next fallback is used, then the next, and so on.

Comment: When Stanford first installed a timesharing system for undergraduates, it was babysat by an ubergeek (Richard Gabriel?) who responded to all my questions with "I can tell you that, but is that what you really want to know?"  This question reminds me of those days...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though not directly answering the question of "detecting O/S", you may be able to achieve the desired effect of selecting a font using the [`font-family`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font-family.asp) CSS property.

This property lets you chose a list of fonts, where the browser will try to match fonts available on the system. It reads left-to-right and will use the first font available:

```
body
{
    font-family: "Calibri", "Arial", "Sans Serif"
}
```

In this case, if the "Calibri" font is not available, the system will use "Arial". If "Arial" cannot be found, it will use any available fonts from in the "Sans Serif" family.

With this you can specify your Linux-specific font first and know that other platforms without the font available will display using a suitable font too.

Comment: What's to stop someone from installing these fonts on another system?  What about systems that don't have these fonts installed?  This is a terrible way to detect OS.

Comment: As my answer states, this is not an answer to trying to detect the OS, but how to display a particular font depending on what's available.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post yesterday.  If you were to make an edit, I will happily retract my downvote.  (SO won't let me remove it without an edit of 1 character or so, since it weas ysterday.)  Sorry about the trouble!

Answer (score 14):

examine `navigator.userAgent`

You can generally find what you seek with simple rx but to do so will require a basic understanding of sniffing. You can find a good example [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

NOTE: i am not suggesting that you use a sniffing library, just that you familiarize yourself with what you need to look for.

As far as dynamically controlling fonts by OS, I think that, barring some edge case that is not stated in your question, simply defining a [font stack](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/eight-definitive-font-stacks) is your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

I like to do a combination of jQuery and CSS to solve this issue.  This approach was inspired by modernizr, which dynamically adds all of the browser's abilities as classes to the html element.

```
// Detect Browser
$.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
  $("html").addClass( i );
  $("html").addClass( val );
});
// Detect Operating System
$("html").addClass( navigator.platform );
```

The result of running the code above gives me this output when I view a page and inspect the DOM.  One issue is that I'm on Mac with Chrome but jQuery's browser object thinks I'm using Safari, which is also a webkit browser.

```
<html class="webkit version 535.1 safari MacIntel">
```

If you print javascript's navigator.useragent you'll get a result with tons of information like this

```
Mozilla-5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
```

`msie` is the jQuery.browser label assigned for IE so I could do something like this in my css without needing conditional statements if I append the browser as a class to the html or body tags:

```
h1 { /* my regular h1 styles */ }

.msie h1 { /* IE edge case styles for h1 treatment */ }
```

In jQuery you could use its fantastic selector engine to search for version #'s and various combos to target issues directly that only apply to specific browser versions and OS combinations.  Just output the entire userAgent string html class, just be sure to clean that string removing the /() characters.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

@Sky had a great link to this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html which could be used to get more accurate browser and OS information which you could append as classes to the HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Rafael's Browser Selector javascript http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ - you'll be able to define browser-, os-, and brower/os combo-specific CSS, in an easy form:

`(.os)(.browser) selector {...;}` (so, e.g. `.opera {color: red;}`)

It supports a lot of os's and a lot of browsers