# Is there a CSS media query to detect Windows?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to specify two slightly different background colors, one for Mac OS, one for Windows.

Comment: Refer to this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661540/detecting-the-operating-system-using-jquery-or-css

Hope it helps.

Comment: consider using http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: Is this just a design choice, or are you doing this to solve some problem?

Comment: Please tell me this isn't to deal with the gamma correction disparity between the two OSes (this was actually remedied in recent versions of Mac OS X).

Comment: -moz-os-version for windows

Answer (score 37, accepted):

there is no property to specify OS used to view webpage, but you can detect it with javascript, here is some example for detecting Operating system :

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

console.log('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

got it?, now you can play with `document.write` to write download stylesheet for specific Operating system. :)

another example, i assumed that you are using jquery.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
{
  $(body).css('background','#333');
} else {
  $(body).css('background','#000'); // this will style body for other OS (Linux/Mac)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it is available in the latest mozilla version.

-moz-os-version provides following values:

- windows-xp
- windows-vista
- windows-win7
- windows-win8

support is limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media (-moz-os-version: windows-xp), (-moz-os-version: windows-vista),
(-moz-os-version: windows-win7), (-moz-os-version: windows-win8) {
    body{
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to not be supported anymore : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/CSS/@media/-moz-os-version

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Firefox could also detect windows (for those who are not using autoupdate) and are using version 4 or newer. It is more basic and does not tell the version, just the fact you are in windows. I created this one for testing a while back because I was curious.

```
@media screen and (-moz-windows-theme) {
    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

this is also covered in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, not possible. At most there's a `@media` filter so you can target mobile devices v.s. desktop devices, but there's no `@os` type filter.

You can achieve it with IE's conditional tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="everyone.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Put the mac-specific styles into the 'everyone' css, and then override whatever's necessary in the IE version.

Of course, this will fail if you get a user who's on an (ancient) IE for Mac version, but should cover all modern users.

Comment: so you're assuming all windows users use internet explorer?

Comment: Sorry man, gotta be OS specific. Windows users also use other browsers