# Change custom cursor based on OS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a custom cursor for my app. But cursors in OSX are black and cursors in Windows are white.

If I create two cursors, one in white and one in black, how do I switch cursors based on the OS using CSS?

```
.custom-cursor-windows {
    cursor: url('windows-cursor.svg') 0 0, auto;
}

.custom-cursor-mac {
    cursor: url('mac-cursor.svg') 0 0, auto;
}
```

Comment: [Not possible using CSS alone. JavaScript is required.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494351/5566355)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS media query to detect Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493589/is-there-a-css-media-query-to-detect-windows)

Answer (score -1):

You would 100% require javascript involvement on this one. You can use the User Agent string in an javascript if statement to determine which CSS class you either want to echo out or set via js itself.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its possible to change it with pure CSS, but you can detect the OS with JavaScript.

Here is an example:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1){
    //change css to win cursor
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) {
    //change css to mac cursor
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't accomplish this without JavaScript. The easy way to check for OS (Windows / Mac) is to examine the `window.navigator.platform` property. In your case a simple string `IndexOf` search for `"Mac"` should be enough to differentiate between the two systems, while defaulting to `Windows` for the likes of Linux, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v08gg9ep/4/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var opsys = getOS();
    if(opsys == "Windows"){
        alert("White Curosr");
      $("html").css("cursor: url('windows-cursor.svg') 0 0, auto");
    }else if(opsys == "iOS" || opsys == "Mac OS"){
        alert("White Curosr");
      $("html").css("cursor: url('mac-cursor.svg') 0 0, auto");
    }
});

function getOS() {
  var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent,
      platform = window.navigator.platform,
      macosPlatforms = ['Macintosh', 'MacIntel', 'MacPPC', 'Mac68K'],
      windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'],
      iosPlatforms = ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod'],
      os = null;

  if (macosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Mac OS';
  } else if (iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'iOS';
  } else if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Windows';
  } else if (/Android/.test(userAgent)) {
    os = 'Android';
  } else if (!os && /Linux/.test(platform)) {
    os = 'Linux';
  }
  return os;
}
```