# Select box `appearance` on Mac /safari or chrome

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

How can I make the `select` box look the same on all web browsers and devices but I can't find the right way to do that, so far the biggest problem is on IE 10 and Microsoft edge, it seems the `appearance` is not working!

can anyone help with this issue? thank you.

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.textfield,
.select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.select {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div>
    <label for="text">
      <nobr>Text field</nobr>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input name="text" tabindex="1" class="textfield" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <br />
    <select name="select" tabindex="2" class="select">
      <option value="">&#45;&#45; Please Select &#45;&#45;</option>
      <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) CSS property

Comment: @JohnEllmore I just edited the post! i meant to say stay away from appearance property. because i don't wanna deal with the arrow and background issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an image as a background to the select field, some people recommended it and its working great.
simply add bellow to `.select` in the css:

```
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* **this should be your icon or image to replace the down arrow** */
  background :url('http://via.placeholder.com/10x10') 95% no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 14px;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the textbox and select box have *exactly* the same appearance style-wise, pick the style you want (i.e. something like `border: 1px solid #666666` to mimic the `<input>` element) and apply it to both your `.textfield` and `.select` classes together.

You can use JavaScript to only apply that style when the user is on a Mac, if you want. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494351/5463636).)

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.textfield,
.select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.select {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.asterisk {
  color: #FF0004;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div>
    <label for="text">
      <nobr>Text field</nobr>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input name="text" tabindex="1" class="textfield" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="select">
      <nobr>Select<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></nobr>
    </label>
    <br />
    <select name="select" tabindex="2" class="select">
      <option value="">&#45;&#45; Please Select &#45;&#45;</option>
      <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the css didn't work @freginold, still didn't try the js

Comment: @Abdal What do you mean, it didn't work? It didn't look the same? You can play around with the color and thickness.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.textfield,
.select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.select {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.asterisk {
  color: #FF0004;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div>
    <label for="text">
      <nobr>Text field</nobr>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input name="text" tabindex="1" class="textfield" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label for="select">
      <nobr>Select<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></nobr>
    </label>
    <br />
    <select name="select" tabindex="2" class="select">
      <option value="">&#45;&#45; Please Select &#45;&#45;</option>
      <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```