# Display css only when running on Windows

Tags: css

I display scrollbars when the mouse is moved over a div as follows:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However, I really only want this to happen when my app is running on a Windows machine and not when it's running on any other operating system. Is this possible using css?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css alone.

Comment: What is the server-side scripting language you're using?

Comment: You can detect browser using script and add the following css using script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS media query to detect Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493589/is-there-a-css-media-query-to-detect-windows)

Comment: Why do you only want this on windows? What seperates chrome/FireFox on windows from chrome/FireFox on Mac or Linux to justify these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by little bit use of jQuery/JavaScript;

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


 function isMacintosh() {
      return navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac') > -1
    }

    function isWindows() {
      return navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1
    }  
    $(window).bind("load", function() { 

 if(isWindows() == true)
    { 
        $('#scroll').attr('style', 'height: 100px;width: 50%;margin: 0 auto;overflow: hidden;');  
         $("#scroll").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css("overflow-y","scroll");
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).css("overflow-y","hidden");
            });
    }

    });

</script>



<div id="scroll">
 Div with ID
</div>

<div>
 Div with out ID
</div>
```

**Note:** For jquery you have to load jquery scripts in header.
hope it will help you.